# Negative absorption coefficient

Tags: spectroscopy, materials, absorption, elemental-analysis, x-ray-diffraction

What does a negative absorption coefficient mean?
In detail - I participated in a Synchrotron virtual laboratory. I have to analyze the results and understand what a negative absorption coefficient means, as you can see in the pictures. The area where the absorption coefficient is negative is the area before XANES.
In the first picture you can see the graph from the theoretical material, and in the second picture the graph from the analysis of the results.
[image: X-ray absorption spectra theoretical]

[image: X-ray absorption spectra]

Comment: Usually it means that there is a little fluorescence effect, or some radiation lost by diffusion.

Comment: you could look at https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Spectroscopy/X-ray_Spectroscopy/XANES/XANES_-_Theory_II

Comment: Thank you!

Fluorescence effect caused by absorption of radiation, so the absorption coefficient should be positive. How is it possible ?